# RequestAnimationFrame not available in Safari - how to do fluid animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, parallax

[This site](http://viclib.com/kevin) runs smoothly in every browser but Safari, because it doesn't have "RequestAnimationFrame". Notice the elements are positioned using JavaScript, and it probably couldn't be done without it. On Safari, I have to use `window.onscroll` to refresh my element's positions, which is not giving fluid results.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9):

Safari 6 [has prefixed support for rAF](http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe).

For cross-browser compatibility, [there's a polyfill for that](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671) which uses timers. Just drop this code in before using rAF.

```
// http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
// http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/12/20/requestanimationframe-for-smart-er-animating
// requestAnimationFrame polyfill by Erik Möller. fixes from Paul Irish and Tino Zijdel
// MIT license
(function () {
  var lastTime = 0;
  var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
  for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
  }
  if(!window.requestAnimationFrame)
    window.requestAnimationFrame = function (callback, element) {
      var currTime = new Date().getTime();
      var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
      var id = window.setTimeout(function () {
        callback(currTime + timeToCall);
      },
      timeToCall);
      lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
      return id;
  };
  if(!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = function (id) {
      clearTimeout(id);
  };
}());
```